# Sync two tables in different postgresql databases using pg_comparator

Tags: postgresql, data-warehouse

I've been trying to build a data warehouse using pg_comparator, to sync specific tables as it is from production. It seems like pg_comparator works well to identify UPDATES, INSERTS and DELETES and syncs record correctly.

Am facing a problem though that pg_comparator causes tables to be locked on production which leads to other problems with live transactions.

```
./pg_comparator -S -D \
      pgsql://calvin@server1/dbname/user pgsql://hobbes@server2/dbname/user
```

Can someone please advise on how can I run pg_comparator without locking source db tables?

Comment: It should really only need to lock the destination tables. The source tables should only need a snapshot. Weird that it takes a heavyweight lock.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://www.cri.ensmp.fr/~coelho/pg_comparator/pg_comparator.html) there is a `--lock, --no-lock` option:

> `--lock, --no-lock`
>   Whether to lock tables. Setting the option explicitly overrides the default one way or another. For PostgreSQL, this option requires --transaction, which is enabled by default.
>
> Default depends on the current operation: the table is not locked for a comparison, but it is locked for a synchronization.